Why is there a save icon and a number next to my git branch in powerhsell oh-my-posh
I am new to using Powershell to do my git commands and on some of my repositories, I see the following symbol:

what does this symbol mean?
I looked up symbols but did not find much. any help would be greatly appreciated!

Welcome to SO, Will. SO is a place where programmers help programmers make source code work. This question is not about source code. That is not to say that it is not important. It is not on-topic for SO. It might be on-topic for https://superuser.com/. On SO, it may attract downvotes and votes to close.

@lit It is on-topic, because this question is about tools primarily used by programmers: git and oh-my-posh (a tool to make a posh prompts in shells, in this case used in combination with git).

@MarkRotteveel, it seems that on-topic appears to be in the eye of the beholder. I was only trying to let this relatively new contributor know that downvotes and votes to close may appear.

This is based on your Git segment template configuration in Oh My Posh. The appearance of icons and numbers is determined by the properties set in your theme's JSON configuration file. Typically, the relevant segment looks like this:
"type": "git",
...
"template": " {{ .UpstreamIcon }}{{ .HEAD }} {{ .BranchStatus }} {{ if gt .StashCount 0 }} \ueb4b {{ .StashCount }}{{ end }}"

Here’s a breakdown of what each part does:

{{ .BranchStatus }}: Displays the status of your branch, often represented by horizontal lines or other symbols.
\ueb4b: This is the save icon from Nerd Fonts, corresponding to nf-cod-save.

The {{ .StashCount }} in this template displays the number of stashed changes if there are any (greater than 0).
For more detailed information, you can refer to the Oh My Posh Git segment documentation and the Nerd Fonts cheat sheet.
